# Survival analysis: showing that the hazard rate function is approximately the probability of dying

Tags: probability, statistics

If you're comfortable with survival analysis, please feel free to skip to the **Question** section. Otherwise, I set up notation for my question here.

### Setup

Let $L$ be a nonnegative continuous random variable such that

$$
\mathbb{P}\{L \geq t\} = e^{-H(t)} = e^{- \int_0^t h(s) ds}
$$

where $H(t)$ is the *hazard function* and $h(t)$ is the *hazard rate function*. I want to show that

$$
h(t) u \approx \mathbb{P}\{L < t + u \mid L \geq t\}
$$

In words, the probability that you do not survive longer than $u$ given that you have already survived for $t$ is proportional to an infinitesimal slice of area under $h(t)$ or roughly the height of $h(t)$.

Consider this derivation:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{L \geq t + u \mid L \geq t\}
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}\{L \geq t + u, L \geq t\}}{\mathbb{P}\{L \geq t\}}
\\\\
&\stackrel{\text{ind}}{=} \frac{\mathbb{P}\{L \geq t + u\}}{\mathbb{P}\{L \geq t\}}
\\\\
&= \frac{e^{-H(t+u)}}{e^{- H(t)}}
\\\\
&= \frac{e^{-\int_0^{t+u} h(s)ds}}{e^{-\int_0^{t} h(s)ds}}
\\\\
&= e^{-\int_0^{t+u} h(s)ds + \int_0^t h(s)ds}
\\\\
&= e^{- \int_t^{t+u} h(s)ds}
\end{align}
$$

So the probability of not surviving in $u$ years if you have lived $t$ years is given by

$$
\mathbb{P}\{L < t + u \mid L \geq t\} = 1 - \mathbb{P}\{L \geq t + u \mid L \geq t\} = 1 - e^{- \int_t^{t+u} h(s)ds}
$$

Now let $F_t(u) = 1 - e^{- \int_t^{t+u} h(s) ds}$. Therefore,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{L < t + u \mid L \geq t\} &= F_t(u)
\\\\
\lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \mathbb{P}\{L < t + u \mid L\geq t\} &= \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} F_t(u)
\\\\
\lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{P}\{L < t + u \mid L \geq t\}}{u} &= \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{F_t(u)}{u}
\\\\
\lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{P}\{L < t + u \mid L \geq t\}}{u} &= \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{F_t(u) - F_t(0)}{u}
\end{align}
$$

where the last step holds because $F_t(0) = 1 - e^{0} = 0$.

#### Question

Here is what I don't understand. The next step in the course notes is

$$
\lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{F_t(u) - F_t(0)}{u} = \frac{\partial}{\partial u} F_t(u) \Bigg|_{u=0} = h(t) \tag{$\star$}
$$

But I am used to the definition of a derivative as being

$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x)
$$

and I am unable to see why $\star$ holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function of two variables $F(t,u)$ (written $F_t(u)$ for your example), then the *partial derivative with respect to $u$* is defined by $$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}F(t,u) =\lim\limits_{s\to 0}\frac{F(t, u+s)-F(t,u)}{s}.$$
To evaluate this at $u=0$, we put $u=0$ on the right-hand side, so
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}F(t,u)\Bigg|_{u=0}=\lim\limits_{s\to 0}\frac{F(t, s)-F(t,0)}{s}.$$
Writing it with the subscript $t$ notation used in your example (so $F(t,s)=F_t(s)$ and $F(t,0) = F_t(0)$), we see that we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}F_t(u)\Bigg|_{u=0} =\lim\limits_{s \to 0}\frac{F_t(s)-F_t(0)}{s}.$$
You can now change the $s$ to $u$ if you want, it is just a dummy variable for the limit. This matches the equation your notes had. (If you want to see why this equals $h(t)$, you will need to differentiate $F_t(u) = 1-e^{-\int_t^{t+u}h(s)\, ds}$ with respect to $u$ (using the chain rule and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus), and then substitute in $u=0$.)